# Why is irreducible $x^{3n}+x^2y+xy^2+y$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$?

Tags: extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I know how to prove that a polynomial is irreducible if it has one variable, but I don't know how to proceed with this problem:

> Prove that for any positive integer $n$, the polynomial $x^{3n}+x^2y+xy^2+y$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.

Can anyone give me a hint or explain me how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eisenstein criterion in $\mathbf Q[y][x]$: $y$ divides  all coefficients of the polynomial, but the leading coefficient, and $y^2$ doesn't divide its constant term.

Comment: It's considering $x,y$ primes in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$?

Comment: More exactly, $y$  is prime in the P.I.D. $K[y]$ ($K$ any field).